# how to make a guessing game in python I am struggling

Tags: python

here is my code

```
import random
print ('hello')
print ('my name is IB what is your name')
mn = input()
print ('it is good to meet you ' + mn+ ' I am thinking of a nomber 1 to 
100')
it = 1
jojm = random.randint (1, 100)
print ('guess')
guess =input()
while it < 100:
    if guess == jojm:
        print ('game over ')
        break
    elif guess < jojm: #it keeps saying the problem is here
        print ('to low')
        print ('guess')
    elif guess > jojm:
        print ('to high')
        print ('guess')
    it = it + 1
print =it
```

I have no idea what to do please help I will need it if anybody can help please do

Comment: There is no real reason to loop 100 times. The user might guess the same number twice or guess a number outside the 1-100 range. You might improve to just do an infinite loop. `while True:` and break when they get it right. You can ctrl+c to escape the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should take the input in the loop and also parse it as an integer:

```
while it < 100:
    guess = int(input())
    #rest of your code
```

**TIP** : you can provide prompt text in input method itself like `input('Guess ?')`

Comment: do while is more appropriate than just a while in a guess game.

Comment: @chrisckwong821 python doesn't have do while, you need to emulate that yourself.

Comment: you are right, I come from other languages and didnt realize this.

Answer (score 1):

convert `guess =input()` to `guess =int(input())`

cause `guess =input()` takes a `string` and you are comparing with `int`.

Here you can try this.

```
jojm = random.randint (1, 100)
print('guess')
while True:
    guess = int(input())
    if guess == jojm:
        print ('game over ')
        break
    elif guess < jojm:
        print ('to low')
        print ('guess')
    elif guess > jojm:
        print ('to high')
        print ('guess')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `guess` is a string and you need to covert it to an int:

```
import random
print ('hello')
print ('my name is IB what is your name')
mn = input()
print ('it is good to meet you %s I am thinking of a number between 1 and 
100' % mn)
it = 1
jojm = random.randint (1, 100)
print ('guess')
getGuess = input()
guess = int(getGuess) #convert it first to an integer 
while it < 100:
    if guess == jojm:
        print ('game over ')
    elif guess < jojm: 
        print ('to low')
        print ('guess')
    elif guess > jojm:    
        print ('guess')
        it = it + 1

print (it)
```

Comment: And also your code has other problems but this should work fine

Comment: @jojm It works perfect for me.Just remove the space between line 5 and 6 where it says 100. I had to include the space since it was in an answer.

Comment: Here is an online editor in which I used it and it works pretty much fine: https://repl.it/Mzpc/0
Just go to that link and copy paste everything :-)

Answer (score 0):

put this line

```
guess =input()
```

In the while loop
than every time guess is printing Program will ask you to enter a value.